# Execute a function when starting a Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, startup

I want to execute a function when I start my Laravel application.
Until now I used the boot function of the "AppServiceProvider" but then my function is executed very often.
How can I execute my function once at startup?

This is my code so far:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        SocialController::init();
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to bind a `singleton` it runs only one time

Comment: it would be like this `$this->app->bind(SocialController::class, function ($app) {
    return new SocialController::init();
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an awesome feature in `laravel` [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container) called `Singleton`

this feature everey thing you bind to it works for one time only that is mean that your 
an instance of `class` for example will be the same

it's helpful for something like registering apiToken for third party token as you try i think

so all you need os to write something like this

```
$this->app->bind(SocialController::class, function ($app) {
    return SocialController::init();
});
```